# Why are these multiple WSL distributions on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run Windows 10 with WSL enabled.

Running command `wsl -l -v` results in the following output:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

I was surprised to see two running WSL instances.  Why is this?
Why not a single instance?  And also why the strange name?

Comment: Because you installed Docker Desktop which creates and uses those two WSL instances.

Answer (score 1):

> I was surprised to see two running WSL instances. Why is this?

As mentioned in the comments, these WSL distributions are for *internal use by Docker Desktop*, which you have presumably installed.

They are not meant for end-user use.  Their purposes:

- `docker-desktop`:  Runs the Docker Engine daemon that is used by PowerShell, CMD, Docker Desktop, other WSL distributions, and anything else on your system that needs to make use of it.

  It also contains the end-user tools, such as the `docker` command itself, for other WSL distributions.  The commands are symlinked from `docker-desktop` into your end-user WSL distribution.
- `docker-desktop-data` is where Docker stores all of your containers, images, volumes, etc.

> Why not a single instance?

As mentioned above, when you install a new release of Docker Desktop, it will replace the existing `docker-desktop` distribution with the latest version of the tools.  Keeping your data in `docker-desktop-data` allows the *tools* to be updated without impacting the data itself.

> And also why the strange name?

Hopefully with the above information, the naming makes more sense to you now.

---

Note that if you actually want to use WSL itself, you'll need to install a distribution intended for end-user use.  It is not recommended to run inside the `docker-desktop` distribution itself, as it will get overwritten with new releases.

You can install a distribution from the Microsoft Store.  Some popular ones:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:  currently the default WSL distribution.  Recommended for new users simply because there is so much documentation and support for Ubuntu.
- Debian
- openSUSE Tumbleweed:  a "rolling release distribution"

Note that after installing the distribution, you'll likely need to set it to be the default since Docker was installed first.

From PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v
# Identify the distribution name
wsl --set-default <distribution name>
```